# Why is "ten-minute break" singular but "two weeks' time" uses a plural?

Tags: phrases, phrase-analysis

We say *a ten-minute break*
We say *two weeks' time.*

*Ten-minute* is singular but *two weeks'* is plural, why?

Comment: We would also say *"in ten minutes' time"* and *"a two week break"* It has nothing to do with *ten minute* and *two weeks*; what causes the difference is the words *break* and *time*.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the countability or uncountability of the noun. "time", as used in your phrase, is uncountable, while "break" is countable (notice you say "**a** ten-minute break).

With words used in such phrases which can be either countable or uncountable, we can find both variants:

a. Use of the genitive (the noun has to be uncountable):

- I had three weeks' vacation.

b. Use of a compound noun formed by numeral+singular measure of time (with countable nouns):

- I had **a** three-week vacation.

In your examples, "time" is uncountable and thus uses pattern (a), while "break" is countable and uses pattern (b).